# Calculate a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $y_n = 1/3y_{n-1} + 2/3y_{n-2}$ for $n>2$

Is the below correct? It is from my book but I don't understand how.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y_n = y_1(1 + 2/3 + 2/3^2 +...) + y_2(1 + 1/3 + 1/3^2 +...)$

I try to calculate $y_3$,$y_4$,$y_5$,... but their sum is not clean like the above and there are a bunch of extra terms that don't seem to cancel out. Can someone guide me on this? Thanks!

What I have done:
$y_3 = 1/3y_2 + 2/3y_1$ This one is fine
but starting from $y_4$,
$y_4 = 1/3^2y_2+2/3^2y_1+2/3y_2$,

$y_5 = 1/3^3y_2 + 2/3^3y_1 + 2/3^2y_2 + 2/3^3y_2 + 2/3^2y_1$

For the $y_2$ I still can get $1/3,(1/3)^2,...$, but going forward there seem to be a lot of extra terms that I don't get how they can add up to the above sum.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), especially the parts about showing your work and asking followup questions.

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Comment: did edit it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If uou properly solved $$y_n = \frac 13 y_{n-1} + \frac 23 y_{n-2}$$ you are supposed to have obtained
$$y_n=c_1+c_2\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$ since
$$r^2=\frac 13 r+\frac 23=0 \implies (r-1)\left(r+\frac{2}{3}\right)=0$$ Now, applying the consitions $y_1=a$ and $y_2=b$ gives
$$c_1=\frac{2 a+3 b}{5}  \qquad \text{and} \qquad c_2=\frac{9(b-a)}{10}$$

From here, it starts to be simpler.

Notice that you have a sign error and that $y_0$ is still undefined.